# How to get part of string between something?

Tags: java, string

I have the string `aaabbbccc`.What is the best way to get `bbb` part?

**UPD:**

How to get `ccc` from `aaabbbcccdddfff`?

Comment: The best way depends on your requirement. Is the 'bbb' part will always be between 'aaa' and 'ccc'? Or will it be starting from 4th character always in the given string always? You can acheive the same using various methods like subString, regex, etc.,

Comment: This cannot be answered because we can't tell just from one example what you're really trying to do.  What kind of string are you expecting as input?  Will it always be a sequence of clumps of 3 of the same letter, or could it be something else?  If it's always 3-character clumps, are you asking how to get the one in the center?  And if the number of clumps is even, what do you want it to return?  We need to know (1) what types of strings you're expecting to start with, and (2) what exactly you want done with those strings, in the *general* case, not just one specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.substring(s.indexOf("b"), s.lastIndexOf("b")-1)`

Comment: Cannot resolve method substring

Comment: sorry, had the case wrong on substring. i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
StringUtils.substringBetween("aaabbbccc", "aaa", "ccc")
```

using `StringUtils.substringBetween(...)` from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case,

```
String bbbString = "aaabbbccc".substring(3,6);
```

In response to the bit you just added to your question, I would say use the following function

```
public String getRepetitiveSubstringOf(String string, char desiredCharacter)
{
String theSubstring = null;
char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();   //it is more efficient to use arrays
//get the beginning position
int beginPosition = string.indexOf(desiredCharacter);
//get the end position (the desired substring length might NOT be 3, but rather, in this case, 
//where the character value changes)
int endPosition = beginPosition;
//looping until we have either found a different character, or until we have hit the end of the 
//character array (at the end, we loop one more time so that we can hit a garbage value that 
//tells us to stop)
while ((charArray[endPosition] == desiredCharacter) || (endPosition < charArray.length))
{
    endPosition++;
}
//if we have hit the garbage value
if (endPosition == charArray.length)
{
    //we substring all the way to the end
    theSubstring = string.substring(beginPosition);
}
else
{
    //now, we check to see if our desiredCharacter was found AT ALL in the string
    if (desiredCharacter > -1)
    {
        theSubstring = string.substring(beginPosition, endPosition);
    }
}
return theSubstring;
}
```

From there, you can check for a return value of null

Answer (score 0):

Try [StringUtils.subStringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 String value = "aaabbbccc";
 StringUtils.substringBetween(value, "aaa", "ccc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one line and one method call if you use regex to capture the target group:

```
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*aaa(.*)ccc.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the string that you have specified you can use the code:

```
String result=s.substring(s.indexOf('b'),s.lastIndexOf('b'));
```

where s is your string,

For a more general string:

```
String result =s.substring(first index,last index);
```

where first index and last index are range that you want to extract.
Example:

```
String S="rosemary";
String result=s.substring(4,s.length());
```

This will store "mary" in the result string.

Answer (score 0):

The best way maybe regEx.You could use

String str = str.replaceAll(a